# Creating a matrix and free() problems - c

Tags: c

it seems i have some problems in my code. the first one is that i cant use the free function correctly:"heap corruption detected". 
in the second part of my work i wanted to create a matrix:it puts a red mark under the j and then the compiler says that subscript requires array and pointer type. 
i only wanted to create a two dimension matrix.
thanks for your help!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
char *word[1000] = { 0 }, letter[1000], *temparr, *originalarr;
int i = 0, j = 0, counter = 0, k = 0, w = 0, anagram = 0, size = 0, *mat;
for (i = 0; letter[i] != '\n'; i++)
{
    letter[i] = getchar();
    counter++;
    if (letter[i] == ' ' || letter[i] == '\n')
    {
        if (letter[i] == 10)
        {
            letter[i] = 0;
            word[j] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(counter - 1));
            strcpy_s(word[j], (counter - 1) * sizeof(char*), &letter[i - (--counter)]);
            break;
        }
        if (letter[i - 1] == ' ')
            continue;
        letter[i] = '\0';
        word[j] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*counter);
        strcpy_s(word[j], (counter - 1) * sizeof(char*), &letter[i - (--counter)]);
        letter[i] = ' ';
        counter = 0;
        j++;
    }
}
while (j > 0)
{
    printf_s("%s ", word[j--]);
    if (j == 0)
        printf_s("%s", word[j]);
}
for (j = 0; word[j] != 0; j++)
{
    originalarr = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(word[j])));
    strcpy_s(originalarr, strlen(word[j]) + 1, word[j]);
    for (i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        temparr = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(word[i])));
        strcpy_s(temparr, strlen(word[i]) + 1, word[i]);
        counter = 0;
        if (strlen(originalarr) != strlen(temparr))
            continue;
        for (k = 0; originalarr[k] != 0; k++)
        {
            for (w = 0; w < strlen(temparr); w++)
            {
                printf_s("temparr - %c  ", temparr[w]);
                printf_s("original - %c\n", originalarr[k]);
                if (originalarr[k] == temparr[w])
                {
                    temparr[w] = '0';//problem, but cant be equal to 0
                    counter++;
                    printf_s("counter- %d\n", counter);
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter == strlen(originalarr))
            anagram++;
        free(temparr);//problem
    }
}
k = 0;
size = ceil(sqrt(strlen(letter)));
mat = (int*)malloc((sizeof(int) * size));
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    mat[i] = (int)malloc((sizeof(int) * size));
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        mat[i][j] = '\0';
}
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        mat[i][j] = letter[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `letter[i]` is uninitialized on first use. Undefined Behavior. I'll check for others. Use `letter[1000] = ""` to initialize.

Comment: In `for (i = 0; letter[i] != '\n'; i++)` you are comparing in every loop an uninitialized element of letter. In the next line it gets its value `letter[i] = getchar();`

Comment: `'0'` and `'\0'` (aka `0`) are not the same.

Comment: `word[j] = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(counter - 1));` should use `sizeof *(word[j])` or `sizeof (char)`. You over-allocate by a factor of `8` on x86_64.

Comment: Also in C there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` & friends.

Comment: i do not have any problem with what you mentioned. i have a problem with free(temparr)

Comment: `originalarr = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(word[j])));` should be `originalarr = malloc (sizeof *originalarr * (strlen(word[j]) + 1)); You forgot the additional char for the `nul-byte` at the end of the string. The same applies to `temparr` allocation.

Comment: Incorporate the changes suggested and then edit your question with any further problems. Don't forget to add code to `free` `originalarr` and `mat` when you are done with the contents. If after making changes you still have problems, I'm happy to help further with debugging. You can cure your first `letter[i]` problem with `for (i = 0; (letter[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)` and removed the assignment within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question you need to declare a pointer to a pointer`mat` instead of a simple pointer as you have done. Then allocate as shown.

```
int ** mat;
mat = malloc((sizeof(int*) * size));
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    mat[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * size));
```

You can use this array `mat` as a 2D array `mat[i][j]`